# RDLC Sum-Function for distinct values

Tags: sql, rdlc

I have a specific question for my RDLC Report and a table, which data comes from a StoredProcedure. The looks like this:

```
Object  Price     More Data here...  
======  ========  =======
X       10 $      ...  
X       10 $      ...  
Y       50 $      ... 
Y       50 $      ... 
Y       50 $      ... 
Y       50 $      ... 
Z       20 $      ...
Z       20 $      ...
        Sum(expr)
```

What I now need is **not** the total Sum of those values, but the sum of all distinct values grouped by each object. So the result should be 80 $ (10+50+20)

I have no specific row or column groups. Grouping after Object and adding a grouprow was not my solution, because the sum only has to be at the end of the table. And I didn't find out how to sum after group values...

I tried different functions like Previous(compared the objects) and RunningValue(). But maybe I used them wrong or they showed me that this function can't be used in an Aggregate function. Maybe Maximun() for each Object is another idea, but it gave me the same error.

Within my tunnelview I have now no idea anymore, what can help me with this case. So maybe one of you can help me.

Thanks in advance

// I am currently working with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: SUM(DISTINCT Price)?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/04/28/walkthrough-how-to-get-distinct-values-of-a-column-of-a-sharepoint-list-using-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx) this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to do the distinct sum in the stored procedure like this. If you are using the mysql stored procedure

**sum(distinct`p`.`Price`)**

In rdlc there is aggregate function called the **CountDistinct**  to count the distinct values without the repetition.